# ASP.NET MVC. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку %project%\bin\*.dll

Tags: asp.net, mvc

Есть веб-приложение. При попытке запустить его выдаёт ошибку

[image: Error]

Но данная библиотека на месте! Пытался перестроить решение, удалял и ставил заново библиотеку. Если удалить библиотеку из reference в принципе, то будет ругаться на следующую в списке.

Однако, достав из закормов копию данного проекта (НЕ РЕШЕНИЯ(!), т.е. папки packages в директории с файлом решения нет) и запустив - проблем не обнаружил. Всё заработало! Затем при закрытии VS попросил сохранить файл решения .sln и я сделал это. После этого, при запуске приложения выскакивает окошечко с загрузкой недостающих пакетов из NuGet, появляется папка packages и всё по новой (см. начало). Подскажите, в каком направлении вообще двинуться можно, чтобы решить эту проблему?

Comment: Почему у вас вообще App_global.asax.dll в референсах? Ее генерирует на лету asp.net, при запуске приложения. На эту сборку рефереса у вас точно не должно быть.

Comment: Он изначально был в папке bin. Дело в том, что копия проекта, которую я использовал - это просто релиз, который лежит на серве вместе с проектом. Возможно в этом причина появления этого файла. Но суть не в этом... Проект не работает не из-за конкретного файла. Допустим, я удалю dll-ку App_global.asax, и попробую запустить проект - выдаст такую же ошибку но с ссылкой на ClosedXML.dll (следующая по списку в папке)

Comment: т.е. у вас копия прекомпилированного сайта (по нему прошлись утилитой aspnet_compile)? тогда как вы умудряетесь "перестроить решение", если оно уже полностью прекомпилировано? По вашему скриншоту даже непонятно, в каком месте падает - стектрейс вы вырезали. Хотите решить проблему - или выкладывайте минимальный пример для воспроизведения, или ловите ошибку сами - включайте fusion logs, или хотя бы запустите [sysmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dn798348) и посмотрите какого файла не находит.